# Archive & analyse network logs from NetBSD on another machine

Tags: networking, logging, log-files, netbsd

I want to use the the new NetBSD's NPF firewall on a gateway that also has the legal obligation to log the traffic for 1 year.
To offload the gateway, I though to put the logging stuff (and IDS, quota management, ..) on another machine (probably on Debian).

I though of 2 solutions to do so :

1. recopying the traffic to the other machine

Unlike FreeBSD and OpenBSD, I'm not sure if NetBSD is able to setup this king of port, and if it is, I don't know how.
http://man.netbsd.org/bridge.4 indicates

> The bridge driver currently does not support snooping via bpf(4).

but in an older version it was

> The bridge driver currently does not support snooping via bpf(4) or transparent filtering.

So maybe there's a way, but I don't know where to start, any help ?

2. run tcpdump on the NetBSD machine and continuously sync the log file with the analyse machine

But how ? It has to be reliable and adapted to network log file (ie continuously written).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this machine has an additional 'admin' network port in addition to the ports used for routing traffic?

npf.conf(5) mentions:

```
 procedure "log" {
         # Note: npf_ext_log kernel module should be loaded, if not built-in.
         # Also, the interface created, e.g.: ifconfig npflog0 create
         log: npflog0
 }
```

which implies you should be able to add an appropriate log line to "log" a copy of all traffic to the admin port